# How do I trigger validation on html if I don't have a form

Tags: javascript, html

How do I trigger validation on html if I don't have a form

i.e here i have set the required attribute, but when I click on the Save button the field doesnt get the red outline, I assume this is because instead of SaveButton invoking a form it is calling Javascript, is there a call I can make in the Javascript to trigger the validation ?

```js
function cloneProfile() {
  var newProfileName = document.getElementById("clone_profile").value;
  var origProfile = profile.options[profile.selectedIndex].value;
  var index = profile.selectedIndex;

  if (newProfileName.length == 0) {
    return;
  }
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '/start.clone_profile', true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");
  xhr.send(origProfile + "\0" + newProfileName);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      if (xhr.responseText.startsWith('ok')) {
        document.getElementById("clone_profile").value = "";
        $('#cloneprofilemodal').modal('hide');
        var newProfile = document.createElement("option");
        newProfile.text = newProfileName;
        newProfile.value = xhr.responseText.substring(3);
        profile.add(newProfile);
        profile.selectedIndex = profile.length - 1;

        //TODO is not ordered alphabetically, means wrong one selected but also Default not put at start
        removeAllAlerts(document.getElementById("cloneprofilemodalAlerts"));
      }
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="clone_profile" id="clone_profilelabel">
      Please enter name for new Profile
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="clone_profile" name="clone_profile" aria-describedby="clone_profilelabel" class="largeinputfield form-control" required>
  </div>
  <div id="cloneprofilemodalAlerts">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
    Cancel
  </button>
  <button onclick="cloneProfile();" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
    Save
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: You could make use of the onchange or onblur events

Comment: put it inside a <form> tag

Comment: why not use `<form>`?

Comment: If I use a form doesn't it have to be submitted to something rather than call the function ?

Comment: You should mark the button with `type="submit"`

Comment: you can use preventDefault(). to prevent it from submiting

Comment: This code https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_validation_check works without form using checkValidity() but when I add to my code I still dont get the red outline

Comment: you can use a form tag and prevent default activity for it on click of the button (where you trigger your javascript)

Comment: you can use css to enable the red outline eg:

`input:invalid {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

input:valid {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}`

Comment: @rawk but why isnt it just working as is

Comment: the browser will by default add their styling when the input elements are wrapped around a form element. if it is not the browser will not recognize it.

Comment: A much better question would be why you don't have a form?

Comment: Yes, a form does have to be submitted to something, but that something (although actually _never_ standardized, can you believe it) can be a JavaScript statement -- use `javascript: <statement>` as the value of `action` attribute. Using a "submit" event handler or `preventDefault` call in one are the wrong thing to do semantically -- the former is an event fired as the form is being submitted (not the same thing as what `action` defines), only fires when you click the submit button, if any. `preventDefault` is for *halting* valid submission, it isn't what you want.

Comment: Actually just wrapping with <form> tag does seem to work without any other changes !

Comment: @Kobe `button` elements are "submit" by default (without explicit `type="submit"`).

Answer (score -1):

You could just disable the save button until the input has a greater length than 0, using an event listener:

```js
function cloneProfile() {
  // your code
}

const button = document.getElementById('save-button')
const input = document.getElementById('clone_profile')

input.addEventListener('input', e => button.disabled = e.target.value.length === 0)
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="clone_profile" id="clone_profilelabel">
      Please enter name for new Profile
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="clone_profile" name="clone_profile" aria-describedby="clone_profilelabel" class="largeinputfield form-control" required>
  </div>
  <div id="cloneprofilemodalAlerts">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
    Cancel
  </button>
  <button disabled id="save-button" onclick="cloneProfile();" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
    Save
  </button>
</div>
```

Note, I added an `id` to your button, as well as the `disabled` property.

---

```
input.addEventListener('input', e => button.disabled = e.target.value.length === 0)
```

- We add an event listener to the input, declared earlier
- we listen for the `'input`' evnet (or oninput), and go on to provide a callback function
- We take the passed parameter, e, which is the event.
- We can access the button from earlier, and its disabled property, using `button.disabled`
- We access the input element itself using `e.target`, and then the value of that input using `.value`, and then the length, using `.length`
- Since we are checking it is equal to 0, the statement will evaluate to true or false

Comment: you could for a more robust input validation you can use the constraint validation API 
eg. e.target.validity.valid

Comment: Thanks its anice idea, but doesnt help me understand why my code is not working.

Comment: You should call the event listener once when the document is loaded -- you can't assume the input is empty or non-empty -- the user agent is free to fill it out automatically, which the "Save" button "disabled" state depends on.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I belive you were looking for, with everything gathered from the comments

```js
function cloneProfile() {
  console.log("run your code here")
}

const button = document.getElementById('save-button')
const input = document.getElementById('clone_profile')

input.addEventListener('input', e => button.disabled = !(e.target.validity.valid))
```

```css
input:invalid {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

input:valid {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="clone_profile" id="clone_profilelabel">
      Please enter name for new Profile
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="clone_profile" name="clone_profile" aria-describedby="clone_profilelabel" class="largeinputfield form-control" required>
  </div>
  <div id="cloneprofilemodalAlerts">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
    Cancel
  </button>
  <button disabled id="save-button" onclick="cloneProfile();" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
    Save
  </button>
</div>
```